# How to process groups in the order they appear in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to run over the below table and each time to process different group. 1st time process childs `3,4,5` of `group 1`, then `8` of `group 4` and then `6,7` of `group 3`.

I tried using **CURSOR** but I didn't managed to get each time different group.

**IMPORTANT**: I must process the groups in the order they appears, namely group #1, then #4 and then #3

**UPDATED**

```
id          group      child
----------- ----------- -----------
1           1           3
2           1           4
3           1           5
4           4           8
5           3           6
6           3           7
```

the query I used is

```
declare @tbl table ( 
        id int identity(1,1) not null, 
        parent int null, 
        child int null);

WITH t1 (parent, child)
AS
(
    SELECT Parentid, Id
    FROM mytable
    WHERE ParentId = 1 and Id <> ParentId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Parentid,Id
    FROM mytable t2, t1
    WHERE t2.ParentId = t1.child            
)

insert into @tbl(parent, child)
SELECT parent,child
FROM t1

SELECT * 
FROM @tbl
```

Thank you

Comment: **THERE IS NO INHERENT ORDER IN SQL**.  Is there another field you are ordering by, or are you just trusting the groups will always appear in this order?

Comment: Just because something isn't possible doesn't mean that the question deserves a downvote.  Shame on you, whoever it was :(

Comment: To clear up JNK's answer: as soon as you do some changes (insert, delete, update) "the order in which they appear" might be completely different!

Comment: @horse:), I know that. In the specific period of time I'll receive the table above and I want to process it in the order it appeared. I don't care if next time it will be in other order.

Comment: As per my answer and JNK's comment, it is always possible, and out of your control, for the order to change even without an INSERT, UPDATE, etc.  SQL Server simply never guarantees the order other than that specified by an ORDER BY.

Comment: @Dems, I don't understand how your answer relates to my question? Don't worry about the order it will appear **NEXT** time. Assume you get the table in any order and you need to process it in the order it appeared at the time you started. For example, if, when you started, the group was in the order 1,5,3 so process it in this order if next time it will be in the order 3,1,5 so process it in that order

Comment: @Theateist - THERE IS NO ORDER WITHOUT AN ORDER BY.  I'm not sure how much clearer we can be about this.  Just because data appears in a certain order in the select does not mean it is actuallt in that order - it's just how it's output.  You need a field to order on.  **PERIOD**

Comment: @JNK, can you suggest how I can change my **WITH CLOUSE** that  will add row_number for each row?

Comment: @Theateist - Add an `INT IDENTITY` field to your table.  This will increment as rows are added, then use it in an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @JNK, I updated my post. I added id column and changed the result. Does this help to write query that will retrieve me groups in the order 1,4,3 and not 1,3,4?

Comment: Why do you need to process it in any specific order? What are you not telling us? The need for order is not apparent in the code you  posted. (And please don't use a cursor whatever you do!) Knowing the real problem makes it easier to help you to the correct solution.

Comment: Even ignoring all of the other good points made so far, I don't think any one else has asked what happens if groups are interleaved (i.e, by whatever means you achieve your ordering, you get a group 4 row, a group 3 row, a group 4 row, a group 3 row) - you sample data only shows contiguous groups.

Comment: @HLGEM, The result of the table is actually tree and I need to copy it to another table. The order I receive is from the root to childs. So, if I would receive it in the order 4,1,3 I will get error because adding node=4 with parentid=1 will raise error because node=1 doesn't exist yet. And If i would receive it in the order 1,4,3 no erros wolud raise. I'll add node=1, then node=4 with parentid=1 and then node=3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `MIN` grouping function to sort parents by the order in which they first appear in the sequence. A ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()` will get the ordinal position of each parent.

```
SELECT parent,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY MIN(id)) [ranking]
FROM t1
GROUP BY parent
ORDER BY [ranking]
```

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server doesn't guarantee the order of records, unless you specify an ORDER BY.

Even when inserting them directly into a table, and reading them back, parrallelism, storage considerations, indexes, and all-sorts (my technical term) can cause them to be read back in a different order.

This doesn't mean you get a different order every time, just that you can't guarnetee the order without the ORDER BY.

In your case, this means that you need another column to state what order the data was inserted.  An easy way of doing that my be just to create an IDENTITY column on the table.  The order the data is inserted will then be preserved in that column, and you can use it in an ORDER BY.

Comment: it's not important if I'll get everytime in other order. I update my post. I added the query by which I get this table. In the specific period of time I'll receive the table above and I want to process it in the order it appeared.

Comment: @Theateist - What he's saying is the order you get it in from the `SELECT` is not guaranteed to be consistent.  You can query the same data twice in a row with the same syntax and get 2 different orders.

Comment: @Theateist - It's the same situation.  You could be the only user logged in to the server, insert the data, and then read the data, yet still have no guarantee that the order would be the same.  Only by using an ORDER BY can you ensure the order, and so when you INSERT the data, you'll need to also record the order at that time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ranking functions `RANK()` and `ROW_NUMBER()`, together with an `ORDER BY` clause to clarify the order of results.

```
SELECT parent, child,
    RANK() OVER (ORDER BY parent) [group],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY parent ORDER BY child) [item]
FROM t1
ORDER BY parent, child
```

Comment: I tried your script and it retrieve groups in the order 1,3,4 and not 1,4,3. I update my post and it uses now identity column. Can I now get the groups in the order 1,4,3?

Comment: Adding an identity column changes everything. So I have posted a new answer.

Answer (score -1):

This script will return EXACTLY what I need. It returns group in the order 1,4,3 and not 1,3,4
The script and the result are below.

```
declare @tbl table ( 
            id int identity(1,1) not null, 
            parent int null, 
            child int null);

    WITH t1 (parent, child)
    AS
    (
        SELECT Parentid, Id
        FROM mytable
        WHERE ParentId = 1 and Id <> ParentId
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Parentid,Id
        FROM mytable t2, t1
        WHERE t2.ParentId = t1.child            
    )

    insert into @tbl(parent, child)
    SELECT parent,child
    FROM t1

    select id, parent
    from (select max(id) as id, parent
         from @tbl
         group by parent) t
    order by t.id
```

The result

```
 id          parent
----------- -----------
3           1
4           4
6           3
```